# How to get console value or <div> by ID from HTML

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio

I'm trying to use C# in Visual-studio 2015 to retrieve a console or get value from `<div>` by `ID="show"` on .HTML file.

Here is my C# code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
namespace Examples.System.Net
{
public class WebRequestGetExample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create a request for the URL.        
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080/trymyown/computeArea.html");

        // If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        // Get the response.
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

        // Cleanup the streams and the response.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Here is my .HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<title>computeArea</title>

  </head>
  <body>

<div id="show"> </div>

<script>
    // This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle.
    // When the user clicks on the polygon an info window opens, showing
    // information about the polygon's coordinates.

    var map;
    var build;

    function initMap() {            
      // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
      var RoundList = [
          {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
          {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
          {lat: 18.400, lng: -65.118},
          {lat: 19.551, lng: -60.164},
          {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
      ];

      // Construct the polygon.
      build = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: RoundList
      });
    }

    function showArea()
    {

var area = parseFloat(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(build.getPath())) * 0.000247105; //this
        area = area.toFixed(4);
        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = area;

        console.log(area);

        //document.write("Area = ");
        //document.write(area);
    }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCVK8oA9vvEBK0CSSvD8haB5i1QYreHmmA&callback=initMap"></script>

<script>
    setTimeout(function(){ showArea(); }, 100);
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

But I ran into some problems!
I could only got all the HTML "code".

Could anyone please helps me to figure it out?

Comment: post your code instead of pictures.

Comment: Try exploring and using [`Html Agility Pack'](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack).

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first time to use, immediately change

Comment: Your current implementation does not take into account, that the content of your desired `div` is generated by client-side js. You need to use a (browser) component that will execute client-side js instead of just downloading the html page source.

Comment: @Filburt
I just want to let c# called by c++ then get get value from HTML, I'm wondering, which kind of project should I create, C# Windows Form  application or C#  Console application ? thanks !!

Comment: This depends on the actual problem you are trying to solve. In my opinion, if you need to scrape a web page to get the data you need, you are either accessing data that is not meant to be used that way or you are overlooking a simpler way provided by an API/web service. Look into other question here dealing with screen scraping - there are plenty.

Comment: @HariPrasad thanks your suggestion, I found someone's implementation and I changed to which I want to do, but Html Agility Pack seems could only parse a file offline, isn't it ? For example, the value of id="show" which I'm going to get have to computed by googlemapAPI. If it's a offline method, I can only get "null" ...

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if i understood the question correctly or not, but i think you want to extract the content of the div, use below:

```
string strRegex = "<div\\sid=\"show\">(.*?)</div>";
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(responseFromServer, strRegex))
{
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(responseFromServer, strRegex).Value.Replace("<div\\sid=\"show\">", "").Replace("</div>", ""));
 }
```

Hope this is what your are looking for.